# Improving NDSolve computation speed for 3D stationary PDE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, mesh, finite-element-method

Continuing my last [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90089/increasing-ndsolve-computation-range-for-3d-stationary-pde), I am trying to solve 3D Schrodinger equation (with mass equals to 1) and with no potential (I will add a potential later). 
The analytical solution for this equation is simply the spherical harmonics times the spherical Bessel function.

As in my last question, I defined:

```
rCoor[x_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2]
θCoor[x_, y_, z_] := ArcTan[z, Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]    
ϕCoor[x_, y_, z_] := ArcTan[x, y]
YlmCart[l_, m_, x_, y_, z_] := SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, θCoor[x, y, z], ϕCoor[x, y, z]]
```

Now I'm trying to solve the equation, with `l = m = 0` (the spherical harmonic paramters) and for energy parameter of `Ef = 1`:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
l = 0;
m = 0;
Ef = 1;
kf = Sqrt[2 Ef];
rmax = 15 kf^-1;
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, rmax], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 1.2}];
boundary[l_, m_, k_, x_, y_, z_] := 
 SphericalBesselJ[l, k rCoor[x, y, z]] YlmCart[l, m, x, y, z]
op = -(1/2) Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] - Ef u[x, y, z];
sol = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 
    boundary[l, m, kf, x, y, z] , True]}, u, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh];
```

This is working just fine for small range, but I'm trying to solve it for much larger range, like `rmax = 1000 kf^-1` or even more. After `rmax = 30 kf^-1` the computation becomes very very slow and does not finish.

I broke the NDSolve to parts and found out that the longest part is in the `LinearSolve` function, which for `rmax = 30 kf^-1` has to solve about 180,000 equations.

What can I do to speed things up?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the size of the `LinearSolve` call is directly dependent on the size of the mesh.  You could increase the `"Length"` of your mesh, but you have to balance that against the loss of accuracy.  I expect `LinearSolve` does its work as fast as is possible.  Perhaps someone else will know more.

Comment: Yes, it is directly dependent on the `Length` of the mesh. The question is how to overcome this obstacle. Is there a way to change the mesh resolution and still get accurate results? Is there a way to speed up LinearSolve? Maybe change some settings?

Comment: Have a look at the section [Solving Memory-Intensive PDEs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) in the documentation.

Comment: @AmitAbir  Why not solve the equation in spherical coordinates rather than Cartesian coordinates?  Also, if the number of modes in theta and phi is small, why not expand the differential equation in spherical harmonics?

Comment: @bbgodfrey When I'm using spherical coordinates, I get the following message: `The PDE coefficient {{-(1/2),0,0},{0,-(1/(2 r^2)),0},{0,0,-(Csc[\[Theta]]^2/(2 r^2))}} does not evaluate to a numeric matrix of dimensions {3,3}.` I thought that FEM does not work with non constant coefficients.

Comment: @AmitAbir  I believe that it does, although I am not certain.  In any case, I do not think that your error message is related to FEM.  The key question is, what problem do you ultimately wish to solve.  For instance, what is the symmetry of your potential.  If spherical, you can reduce your problem to 1D, and almost anything works.  Even 2D would be enormously simpler computationally.  How you should proceed depends on details.

Comment: @user21 Thank you for the reference, I tried everything they have suggested there and it didn't help. Order one mesh gives crappy results, changing the method for LinearSolve helps a little, but for `rmax = 40 kf^-1` it takes 600 seconds to finish. Do you have some other ideas?

Comment: @bbgodfrey Unfortunately I have a potential with no symmetries at all. It is a crystal whose potential is according to some data on the internet, I don't even have an analytic formula for it. There is no way to separate the variables.

Comment: @AmitAbir  Do you wish then, to solve the 3D Schrodinger for a unit cell with periodic boundary conditions?  This may require rather different resolution than the test problem you are exploring now.  So, I suggest you create a simple test problem with no symmetry.  The key features to capture are the scale lengths of the variations of the potential and the wavelength of the wave function.  It may be that this is beyond the ability of Mathematica.

Comment: @bbgodfrey No periodicity, just solve for a single cell. What I did here is my test problem, but I can't even solve it without a potential, so how will I be able to do is with a potential? Do you want to continue on chat?

Comment: @AmitAbir  A potential may not require much more memory.  And, one option in the reference provided by User 21 does save significant memory; see my answer below.  Nonetheless, it seems likely that you will not be able to solve the problem described in your comment without developing suitable approximations.  I wish I could be of more help.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the specific parameters in the question,

```
rmax = 15 kf^-1;
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, rmax], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 1.2}]
(* ElementMesh[ ..., {TetrahedronElement[<10795>]}] *)
MaxMemoryUsed[sol = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == boundary[l, m, kf, x, y, z] , True]},
    u, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.974145, 315694792} *)
```

In other words, for these parameters `NDSolve` uses a mesh to almost `10000` tetrahedrons and `300MB` of memory.  Computational time is negligible on my four-processor PC.  (Typically, these computations use about 60% of my total CPU capacity.)  Both memory and run-time can be reduced by using the `NDSolve` option

```
Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", "LinearSolveMethod" -> {"Pardiso"}}
```

as described in [Solving Memory-Intensive PDEs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html).  (My thanks to User21 for suggesting this reference.)  The new timing and memory usage are

```
(* {0.780953,161811160} *)
```

Thus, the answer to the specific question posed is to use the "Pardiso" `LinearSolve` option to reduce memory requirements by between half and two-thirds.

Of course, using this option only delays the point at which the problem becomes too large for a PC.  For instance, I run out of memory on an 8GB PC just beyond

```
rmax = 30 kf^-1;
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ball[{0, 0, 0}, rmax], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 1.1}]
(* ElementMesh[ ..., {TetrahedronElement[<121663>]}] *)
MaxMemoryUsed[sol = NDSolveValue[{op == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == boundary[l, m, kf, x, y, z] , True]},
    u, {x, y, z} ∈ meshMethod -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "LinearSolveMethod" -> {"Pardiso"}}}]] // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {91.0104, 4829279056} *)
```

[image]

To save more memory, one could design a [custom mesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html) with high resolution in the radial direction and low resolution in the angular directions, appropriate for small `l` and `m`.  Unfortunately, the problem described by the OP in comments above may require high resolution in all directions.